# ASCII to two byte signed binary conversion

Tags: python, endianness

I have an ASCII.txt file(contains integers) which I need to read and convert into two byte signed little endian in Python. I am totally a newbie in this, While trying I am getting the below error.. Kindly help.

```
input- data_array= [1100, 10111, 100010, 101101, 111000, 1000011, 1001110, 1011001, 1100010, 1010111, 1001100, 1000001, 110110, 101011, 100000, 10101, 1011]
```

```
def as_signed_little(data_array):
    as_bytes = int((data_array, 2)).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)
    return as_bytes

I am trying to convert data_array into two bit signed little endian format using the above function. Where am I going wrong. I am new to python. Please help.
```

Comment: It's called "little endian", in case you need to look in the documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi sure. I have an ASCII file, which I need to convert to little endian binary format.  Its actually a sensor data in ASCII format which we convert into little endian binary format. Is there any python module available for such conversion? I am searching but not able to comprehend.

Comment: What is your expected output? Are 12 and 23 two separate numbers, so they get written as (hex) 0c, 00, 17, 00, or are they to be interpreted as the two bytes of a single number, written as 0c, 17?

Comment: Yes 12 and 23 are two separate numbers and to be interpreted as two bytes little endian format. for example 1 is stored as 01 00.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert to `list` of integers (what you have now is a list of strings)
2. Convert to `numpy.array` using a specific `dtype`
3. Convert to bytes using `tobytes()`